# How to remove pip from python in msys2 enviroment?

Tags: python, pip, msys

I installed pip on msys2 (portabledevops) with  `python get-pip.py`
but I get this error

```
$ pip search youtube_dl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'

$ pip install --upgrade
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

How to remove pip completely and install again? I have python2 and python3 installed both

Answer (score -1):

Simple command: `python -m pip uninstall pip`

it will work because pip is also a module